# Can change background with background-color, but not background-image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I cannot get my background to change for some reason. It will change if I use `background-color: #000` but not if I use `background-image: url();` it will not work.

Here is the two ways I have tried so far:

```
document.body.style.background="url('CloudWallpaper.jpg') no-repeat right top";


background-image: url(CloudWallpaper.jpg);
```

Neither of those will work. Any ideas on why or what could possibly be interfering with it?

Comment: Is CloudWallpaper.jpg in the same directory as the page being loaded?

Comment: what problem it gives did you look at the console?

Comment: Yes it is in the same DIR

Comment: Not the same directly as the page. The default directory will be the directory the css file is in.

Comment: MarkM makes a valid point. I assumed inline CSS -- my mistake.

Comment: Are you sure the image url is correct? Where lies the script (path), and where the url?

Comment: That was my problem! Thanks! If you post that as an answer MarkM I will check it as the right answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('CloudWallpaper.jpg')";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<html>
<body style="background-image:url('image.jpg')">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using html for your background change

```
<html>
<body background="background.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

or for links

```
<html>
<body background="http://www.cooness/coolimage.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not really the way to go, especially by modern web design standards. With this approach, you have to edit both HTML and CSS to change things that could (and should) be changed by only editing CSS.

Comment: That will also work, but I don't think that I can make a fixed background by doing it that way

Answer (score 0):

Is your `.css` file inside a folder? Then try `background-image: url("../CloudWallpaper.jpg");`